# Unreal Engine 4 C++ Change StaticMeshComponent of AStaticMeshActor

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

I am trying to change every Static Mesh Actor's Material property. I know I need to iterate over each Actor and find Static Mesh Component. However, I can not modify Material properly.

Here is my code,

```
GEngine->AddOnScreenDebugMessage(-1, 5.f, FColor::Red, TEXT("START Modeling()"));

//Find Actor and change Material
UWorld* world = GetWorld();

//Material Path
FString matPath = "Material'/Game/StarterContent/Materials/M_Metal_Gold.M_Metal_Gold'";
//Material Instance
UMaterialInstanceConstant* material = Cast<UMaterialInstanceConstant>(StaticLoadObject(UMaterialInstanceConstant::StaticClass(), nullptr, *(matPath)));
//Iterate Every Static Mesh Actor
for (TActorIterator<AStaticMeshActor> ActorItr(world); ActorItr; ++ActorItr)
{
    AStaticMeshActor *Mesh = *ActorItr;
    //Just for Degbuging Purpose
    GEngine->AddOnScreenDebugMessage(-1, 5.f, FColor::Red, FString::Printf(TEXT("Actor: %s"), *(ActorItr->GetName())));
    GEngine->AddOnScreenDebugMessage(-1, 5.f, FColor::Red, FString::Printf(TEXT("Location: %s"), *(ActorItr->GetActorLocation().ToString())));
    //Get Static Mesh Component
    TArray<UStaticMeshComponent*> MaterialComps;
    Mesh->GetComponents(MaterialComps);
    //I get this code from community answer. I do not know how it works.
    for (int32 Index = 0; Index != MaterialComps.Num(); ++Index)
    {
        UStaticMeshComponent* targetComp = MaterialComps[Index];
        int32 mCnt = targetComp->GetNumMaterials();
        for (int i = 0; i < mCnt; i++)
                    //This is the core code which actually changing material.
            targetComp->SetMaterial(0, material);
    }

}
```

**Before**
[image]
**After**
[image]

It is occurred to me because I am changing every actor by iteration.
However, It only change floor actor's material.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are changing only the material with the index 0.

Change `targetComp->SetMaterial(0, material);` to `targetComp->SetMaterial(i, material);`. It should fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks to answer my question!